# How to add validation in template driven form in ionic 3?

Tags: angular, validation, ionic3, ngmodel

How to validate mobile number in ionic 3, here i have used ng model, is there any example for it to get done ?

```
    <ion-list>
        <ion-item margin-bottom>
            <ion-input type="number" id="phone"   name="phone"  [(ngModel)]="data.phone" #username="ngModel" placeholder="Mobile"></ion-input>
         
        </ion-item>



        <ion-item margin-bottom> 
            <ion-input type="password" id="password" name="password"  [(ngModel)]="data.password" placeholder="*Password"></ion-input>
        </ion-item>

        <div style="text-align:center;">
            <button ion-button color="primary" type="submit" (click)="login()">
        <ion-icon ios="ios-log-in" md="md-log-in"></ion-icon>
      Login</button>
        </div>
    </ion-list>
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

**.html file code**

```
<ion-list>
    <ion-item margin-bottom>
        <ion-input type="number" id="phone"   name="phone"  [(ngModel)]="data.phone" #username="ngModel" placeholder="Mobile" (ionChange)='validateForm()'></ion-input> 
        <br/>
        {{phoneErrorMessage}}
    </ion-item>

    <ion-item margin-bottom> 
        <ion-input type="email" id="email" name="email"  [(ngModel)]="data.email" placeholder="*Password" (ionChange)='validateForm()'></ion-input>

        <br/>
        {{emailErrorMessage}}
    </ion-item>

    <div style="text-align:center;">
        <button ion-button color="primary" type="submit" (click)="login()">
            <ion-icon ios="ios-log-in" md="md-log-in"></ion-icon>Login
        </button>
    </div>
</ion-list>
```

**.ts file code**

```
public phoneErrorMessage = '';
  public emailErrorMessage = '';
  public data = {email:'',phone:''}
  validateForm(){
      var phoneValidationFlag = false ;
      var emailValidationFlag = false ;
  
      if (this.data.phone == "") {
          this.phoneErrorMessage = "Name must be filled out";
          phoneValidationFlag = false ; 
      }else{
          this.phoneErrorMessage = '';
          phoneValidationFlag = true;
      }
  
      var emailRegex = /^[a-zA-Z0-9.!#$%&'*+/=?^_`{|}~-]+@[a-zA-Z0-9-]+(?:\.[a-zA-Z0-9-]+)*$/;
      if (!emailRegex.test(this.data.email)){  
          this.emailErrorMessage =  'Please enter valid email';
          emailValidationFlag = false
      }else{
          this.emailErrorMessage = '';
          emailValidationFlag = true;
      }
  
      return (emailValidationFlag && phoneValidationFlag) ? true : false ;
  }
  
  
  login(){
      if(this.validateForm()){
          //everything validated and you can excute your api call in this if section
      }
  }
```

Comment: yeah thanks, but i didn't use form group here, i just used ng model, is there any way to add validation in this ng model method ?

Comment: yeah but better you go the built in function. if you want to do this with ngModel then you can write down code in `login` function . where you will check your ngmodel value .

Comment: yeah okay, then how can i validate mobile number or email, can i put the ng pattern for phone number and email inside the html ?

Comment: I have updated my answer for email validation similarly you can put regex for phone number and validate this .

Comment: yeah i found it but this answer is only applicable when we hit the submit button,isn't it ? can't we do this on the run time like when we typing the wrong phone number or wrong format of email, the error msg  would appear below the text field, thats what i am expecting , is there a way to do that ?

Comment: you can create a separate function where it will just validate this form ,. and you can call this function on `keyup` `keydown` and `blur` any event you want as per your requirment if u don't want to do this on submit ..  but just make sure submit event should be part fo that function else it will auto submit the form if it found everything is correct

Comment: i will vote up this for sure, but would you able to provide the solution ? sorry i'm new to this.

Comment: dear i have already provided you solution for what you have asked please let me know what error you are yet facing so that i can provide you solution accordingly

Comment: you have never mentioned in your question like you want a error message to be displayed automatically without clicking on any button. still i have shared my solution to do the same.. still you don't want to do vote up its your choice.

Comment: I voted up but its saying that I should have 15 reputations in order to do that action..

Comment: yeah you have provided the solution but keyup, blur thats what i'm asking, like you updated the answer you can put this keyup and blut functions thats what i am asking bro.

Comment: I have updated my answer .. please have a look and let me know if it is fine now

Comment: yeah i guess it would, you have mentioned email pattern as var and assigned in it whereas i need to do the same with phone number with phone pattern right ?

Comment: yeah i already upvoted but its saying that i should have 15 reputations or more to do that action bro